# gitlab doesn't ignore file

Tags: git, jar, gitlab, gitignore

I have this line in the .gitignore file at the root of my project

```
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
```

But when I do push, I still get the message

> remote: GitLab: File name gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar was blacklisted by the pattern .(jar|war|ear|class\b|keep|dll|exe|msi|pbl|pbd|zip|rar|tar|gz|7z|doc\b|docx|docm|dot|dotx|dotm|xlt|xltx|xltm|ppt|pptx|pptm|pot|potx|potm|vsd|vdx|key\b)$.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

That error message is shown in the user manual for GitLab's Push Rules:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html

Basically, it says you can configure a GitLab instance to forbid pusshing certain types of files. These rules will be applied regardless of what your `.gitignore` file says, so I expect you have to reconfigure your GitLab instance if you want to allow this `.jar` file.

According to that manual page, you should be able to change the rules by modifying `files_blacklist.yml` first.

Answer (score -1):

With prefix `!` you have included the file again, see [Git Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will become included again.

To ignore `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` change the line in .gitignore to the following:

```
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
```